# Select all keys from query in URL without loop - regex does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Looking for one-line solution to convert query string into array of keys from this URL.

```
console.log(location.search.replace('?', '').match(/([^=&]+)=[^&]*?/gi))
```

This expression returns this list :

```
["route=", 
 "token=", 
 "filter_range_period=", 
 "filter_range_start_date=", 
 "filter_range_end_date=", 
 "filter[range][period]=", 
 "filter[range][start]=", 
 "filter[range][end]="]
```

**Question :** why does this regex adds "=" to each group if it is outside of the selection?

**Live example :** https://regex101.com/r/eN9fP1/1

Answer (score 0):

Please use `url.parse` instead. It's the right tool here.

Comment: could you provide link to this function because I cannot find it?

Comment: sorry, it is not nodejs, it is client javascript